# How to Customise my Tabbar controller icons (background images)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

[image]

I have an iphone application in which i wanted to show my own images as the tabbar icons.but now only the default greyone is coming.i need to change it to the my own images?.I went through lot of links,but nothing seems to be very clear.that can anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: @TheSaad  edited my question pls see that?

Comment: are you talking about this

objMoreTabController.tabBarItem.image=[ UIImage imageNamed:@"moreTabImage"];

Comment: Not at all.i want to display my own images in the tabbarinstead of the default one.can we do it with UItabbarcontroler?

Comment: u mean u want to change whole look of tabbar?

Comment: i clearly want to have this images in the tabbar instead of the default ones with the same color as it is.when selected i need to change the image of the icons.thats all

Comment: put a check in your barcontroller and check if a prticular tab is selected, change it's image

Comment: but i was not able to see the orginal color,seing in grey color

Comment: yeah that's the tint color or the tabbar, default selected color is blue, you can change it by change the ting color

Answer (score 1):

Please download source code from [here](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomTabBar) and change images according to your requirement.

Comment: i want this to be achived with my UItabbarcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

You can set image on tabBarItem like this :-

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate = self;
ViewController *viewObject= [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewObject];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tutorial" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"kb-emoji-U+E031.png"] tag:1];
navView.tabBarItem = tabBarItem;
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navView,nil];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

Also see this link - [click me](http://kurrytran.blogspot.in/2011/10/ios-5-tutorial-creating-custom-tab-bar.html)